# What is the difference between YAXPBD and YAXPEBD?

Tags: visual-c++

[ODAC 18.03](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html) setup failed to run on my Windows 10 machine with the message:

```
---------------------------
setup.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR120.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

but 'dependency walker' shows that MSVCR120.dll exists, but has a wrong function names:

[image]

for example, the import is:

```
?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z
```

but the export:

```
?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPEBD@Z
```

the difference is 'E' character.

what does this mean? something like /MT option or something else?

I have VC++ Redist 12.0.30501.0 installed.

Comment: You can run the undname.exe utility from the Developer Command Prompt to decompile these names back to their C++ declaration.  First is `void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)`, second is `void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const * __ptr64)`.  The ptr64 attribute is the difference, that's a 64-bit pointer.  Yes, there are two versions of MSVCR120.dll, the 32-bit and the 64-bit version.  Maybe you are looking at the wrong one, maybe you used the wrong redist installer flavor.  Oracle keeps an army of consultants busy.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, you are right, installing VC Resist 2013 32bit makes Setup.exe run successfully. (But the Oracle C++ DLLs themselves require Resist 2013 64bit).

Comment: Resistance is futile.  Congratulations.

Comment: @HansPassant But it is not clear why Dependency Walker mixes 32 and 64 bit modules.

Comment: I stopped using Depends a long time ago, it isn't reliable enough and has not been maintained in over a decade.  Afaict the author gave up trying to deal with the complications caused by the file system redirector, side-by-side manifests and forwarding, they are very hard problems to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant What is the alternative? What to use to see the dependencies?

Comment: Dumpbin.exe is a basic troubleshooting tool with its /imports and /exports options.  It merely reports their name and avoids trying to find them, that just can't work reliably.